# AutoCompleteTextView popup like Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, maps, autocompletetextview

Hi i'm trying to implement an autocomplete location finder in android, using google maps api, that looks and behaves like autocomplete location finder in the latest Calendar app .

Does anyone know how it's done? Can you point me out some examples/source code that can help me?

I have the autocomplete, using the maps api working. I'm looking for help on how to make the autocomplete  text field slide up/pop up when entering text.

Thanks

***EDIT:***
A link to a small video showing the effect i want to replicate:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9XBupEstm8&

I'm trying to replicate the animation (that happens after typing two chars) where the Textbox goes up and the white background covers all the other components.

I already have the fetch of the places working.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Comment: As i've said i've already implmented that. What i need is guidance on how to "animate" the text box the same way it is done on the calendar app like this [http://imgur.com/a/kH8dK](http://imgur.com/a/kH8dK)